# If let(:thing) is supposed to be memoised per-example, why am I seeing the value when running a second example?

Tags: ruby, rspec

We have this kind of pattern in a spec:

```
describe Thing do
  sanity0 = '../test-data/sanity.mbox'
  let(:sanity1) {
    File.join(@scratch, 'sanity1.mbox').tap { |f|
      FileUtils.cp sanity0, f
    }
  }

  after(:example) do
    FileUtils.rm sanity1
  end

  before(:example) do
    # does stuff using sanity1
    sanity1
  end

  uses_case(proc { [sanity0, sanity1] })

  describe '#method1' do
    it 'does something' do
      # ...
    end

    it 'does another thing' do
      # ...
    end
  end
  # ... more methods ...

end
```

So `sanity1` is used from a `before(:example)`, initialised, and then eventually torn down in the `after(:example)`.

The `uses_case` helper method there is shorthand for a before/after pair which creates more on-disk stuff and then deletes it. The list of files passed in is usually passed as a proc, because otherwise you'd be calling `let` stuff from the wrong place.

```
def uses_case(files)
  before do

    # instance_exec is here because RSpec whines if you call the proc
    # directly instead of in the context of the example.
    files = instance_exec(&files) if files.is_a?(Proc)

    # Uses files to initialise case
  end

  after do
    # cleanup stuff
  end
end
```

The problem is, when the second example runs, it fails:

```
 [java]       Java::JavaIo::FileNotFoundException:
 [java]         File does not exist: /var/folders/d5/p7yfxkhx4673nd7z7lz_t36c0000gn/T/scratch20170525-83837-1r7t2g/sanity1.mbox
```

So it's like the value from the first test somehow floated into the second test... but the cleanup logic was run after that first test, so the file is now gone.

If I inject output lines into the appropriate spots:

```
 [java] Thing
 [java]   #method1
 [java] let(:sanity1)
 [java] cleanup(:sanity1)
 [java]     does something
 [java]     does another thing (FAILED - 1)
 [java]   #method2
 [java]     does something (FAILED - 2)
 [java]     does another thing (FAILED - 3)
```

So clearly it really is only calling it once at the context level.

How can this be the case? If I write a standalone case which just has the examples and no other framework, it behaves in exactly the opposite way, calling both blocks for every single example.

**Edit:** Further reduction, I managed to get it to happen standalone:

```
require 'rspec'

def uses_case(files)
  before do
    files = instance_exec(&files) if files.is_a?(Proc)
  end
end

describe 'something' do
  let(:in_describe) { $stderr.puts('let(:in_describe)'); 'd' }

  uses_case(proc { [in_describe] })

  context 'when context 1' do
    it 'does something' do
      $stderr.puts('in example 1-1')
    end
    it 'does something else' do
      $stderr.puts('in example 1-2')
    end
  end
end
```

Output of that:

```
$ rspec test_spec.rb 
let(:in_describe)
in example 1-1
.in example 1-2
.
```

If I add more diagnostics to that, it gets weirder:

```
--- in before for uses_case ---
self = #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Something::WhenContext1:0x1722011b>
__memoized = #<RSpec::Core::MemoizedHelpers::ThreadsafeMemoized:0x5b3f61ff>
             contents: {}
--- in let(:in_describe) block ---
self = #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Something::WhenContext1:0x1722011b>
__memoized = #<RSpec::Core::MemoizedHelpers::ThreadsafeMemoized:0x5b3f61ff>
             contents: {}

after instance_exec
__memoized = #<RSpec::Core::MemoizedHelpers::ThreadsafeMemoized:0x5b3f61ff>
             contents: {:in_describe=>"d"}

in example 1-1
.--- in before for uses_case ---
self = #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Something::WhenContext1:0x45a4b042>
__memoized = #<RSpec::Core::MemoizedHelpers::ThreadsafeMemoized:0x327af41b>
             contents: {}
after instance_exec
__memoized = #<RSpec::Core::MemoizedHelpers::ThreadsafeMemoized:0x327af41b>
             contents: {}

in example 1-2
.
```

So it looks like, the second time around, it *is* a new hash, and the hash *is* empty, but the `let` block is not called.

Comment: (If someone is wondering about the java lines, yeah, the whole thing is being run from an Ant build... and the Ruby being used here is jruby, although I would hope that it doesn't matter.)

Comment: Does the `FileUtils.cp` block get run more than once?

Comment: Nope, just once.

Comment: @fylooi managed to write a standalone demo anyway, seems to show it calling the let block only once even on normal rspec outside our environment.

Comment: Does it still happen without the `uses_case` call?

Comment: @fylooi the `uses_case` call is the only thing calling the `let` at all, so without it, you get 0 calls to it.

Comment: And if you just call `in_describe` in each example manually?

Comment: @fylooi then it does what you'd expect, calling the block each time.

Comment: Looks like the `instance_exec` is the culprit. RSpec does a lot of metaprogramming to run each spec, eg. each context / example is a dynamically created class, so things behave quite differently from vanilla Ruby. In your case, i'd just pass symbols as identifiers and work with those instead of the actual objects.

Comment: Without the instance_exec, it refused to let me call the let thing since it decided it was being called from an illegal context, but that line is definitely involved somehow.

Comment: IMHO this behavior makes perfect sense. You only define one `proc` and reuse the same `proc` in both tests. Therefore - from the view of that `proc` - the values for `sanity0` and `sanity1` must be the ones created for the first example. You should be able to work around this behavior by creating a new `proc` for every expectation.

Comment: Can you explain what you try to achieve by having multiple `before` and `after` blocks and the usage of the `proc`? It feels to me like this is a code smell. This sound like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me.

Comment: @spickermann The proc is necessary because if you omit it, it calls the `let` thing before the example is running. (Try removing it and running it and you'll see what happens.) The before blocks... the cut-down example only has one, so I'm not sure what you're asking there. If you're referring to the top example, it was extracted from the actual code, which has quite a few helpers which do before/after stuff because we figured that was better than duplicating all the setup/teardown logic for every test (DRY).